# Inconsistency between flex-grow and width on flex items

Tags: css, flexbox

I am playing around with Flexbox in an attempt to learn it on a fundamental level. I am confused by inconsistent results from independent usage of `flex-grow` and `width` on flex items.

Suppose I have the following HTML:

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div id="flex-item-1">1</div>
  <div id="flex-item-2">2</div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

/* 
Within #flex-item-1 and #flex-item-2, toggle between
flex-grow and width to view the different resultant widths 
*/

#flex-item-1 {
  flex-grow: 3;
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 75%;
}

#flex-item-2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 25%;
}
```

When the `width` CSS properties for `#flex-item-1` and `#flex-item-2` are active but the `flex-grow` properties aren't, you can see that the grid lines (made by the HTML and CSS code below) line up with `#flex-item-1` and `#flex-item-2` perfectly.

```html
<!-- 12-column grid lines -->
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
    <div class="col">4</div>
    <div class="col">5</div>
    <div class="col">6</div>
    <div class="col">7</div>
    <div class="col">8</div>
    <div class="col">9</div>
    <div class="col">10</div>
    <div class="col">11</div>
    <div class="col">12</div>
</div>
```

```css
.col {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-left: 1px solid green;
    width: 8.333333%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

[image]

However, when the `flex-grow` properties are active and the `width` properties aren't, the flex items don't line up with the grid exactly:

[image]

Why is this?

Feel free to play around with this example on [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/shandysulen/pen/zYvOwOy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the flex-basis property on your flex-items to 0%

```
#flex-item-1 {
  flex-basis: 0%;
  flex-grow: 3;
  background-color: tomato;
/*   width: 75%; */
}

#flex-item-2 {
  flex-basis: 0%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: pink;
/*   width: 25%; */
}
```

> It specifies the initial size of the flex item, **before** any available space is distributed according to the flex factors. **When omitted from the flex** shorthand, its specified value is the length zero. [Source: mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis)

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-et8snb?file=style.css)

Answer (score 2):

You should add `flex: 1;` on the both `#flex-item-1` and `#flex-item-2` otherwise, the text or the content will affect the `#flex-item-1` width...

Try removing text from the `#flex-item-1`, you will see that everything works as expected.